# ajax global variable with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My issue is about getting the global variable to assign it to item.

```
var cat;  // clicked menu , reference for category, global variable

$(window).ready(function() {


    jQuery(function() {

        $('li.menuItem').click(function(e) {

            cat = $('a', this).text();



            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                timeout: 30000,
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                global: false,
                dataType: "text",
                url: 'items.php?genre=' + cat,
                success:function (data) {
                items(data);// output number of items handled by function items() to make it global
                }
            });




        });
    });

function items(data) { 
// We want this to show the "results" from the  callback function.                 

     console.log(data); // <-- this gives me the right number of items eatch time i click on different category
        }

    $('.pagination').pagination({


        items: ??, <-- my issue is to assign the output data on the fly here,
        itemsOnPage: 20,
        cssStyle: 'light-theme',
        currentPage: 1,
        onPageClick: function(pageNumber) {
            jQuery(".movies-list").html('loading...');
            jQuery(".movies-list").load("connect.php?genre=" + cat + "&page=" + pageNumber);

        }
    });
});
```

I couldn't figure out how to resolve now its been a week or more googling and surfing on StackOverflow without success.
Thank you in advance

Comment: which is the pagination plugin used, is it the [simplePagination](http://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/)

Comment: remove "}" after console.log(data) then replace ?? with data

Comment: also it would be great if you show us you console.log result

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the [simplePagination.js](http://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/), if so you can use the `updateItems` method to update the number of items

```
function items(data) {
    $('.pagination').pagination('updateItems', data);
}
```

Comment: @Jakozi not sure what do meant? just replace your function with the one I posted above and see whether it is working

Comment: like this : function items(data) { // We want this to show the "results" from the callback function.
  $('.pagination').pagination('updateItems', data);
}



        $('.pagination').pagination({

            
            items: 222,
            itemsOnPage: 20,
            cssStyle: 'light-theme',
            currentPage: 1,
            onPageClick: function(pageNumber) {
                jQuery(".movies-list").html('loading...');
                jQuery(".movies-list").load("connect.php?genre=" + cat + "&page=" + pageNumber);

            }
        });



    });

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).pagination is not a function

Comment: @Jakozi try `jQuery('.pagination').pagination('updateItems', data);`

Comment: the same error   Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).pagination is not a function

Comment: looks like you might have multiple jquery versions loaded in your page

Answer (score 0):

yes true i have some external ref so im posting them here:

```
"maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
"ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.3.js"
"maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"
"phpflow.com/demo/jquery_ajax_pagination_with_php_demo/dist/simplePagination.css"
"phpflow.com/demo/jquery_ajax_pagination_with_php_demo/dist/jquery.simplePagination.js"
"fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
"seegatesite.com/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
"seegatesite.com/bootstrap/css/simple-sidebar.css"
"seegatesite.com/bootstrap/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"
```